# Why am I getting these tracebacks?

Tags: python, chatbot, parlai

I'm currently trying out ParlAi by following the quickstart from the [documentation](https://parl.ai/docs/tutorial_quick.html). I already installed ParlAi and currently on *"View a task & train a model"* but when I run the code `parlai display_data --task babi:task10k:1`, I got these tracebacks instead.

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Dean\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 584, in _build_master
    ws.require(__requires__)
  File "C:\Users\Dean\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 901, in require
    needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
  File "C:\Users\Dean\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 792, in resolve
    raise VersionConflict(dist, req).with_context(dependent_req)
pkg_resources.ContextualVersionConflict: (urllib3 1.25.8 (c:\users\dean\anaconda3\lib\site-packages), Requirement.parse('urllib3~=1.25.9'), {'parlai'})

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Dean\anaconda3\Scripts\parlai-script.py", line 6, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "C:\Users\Dean\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 3253, in <module>
    @_call_aside
  File "C:\Users\Dean\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 3237, in _call_aside
    f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Dean\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 3266, in _initialize_master_working_set
    working_set = WorkingSet._build_master()
  File "C:\Users\Dean\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 586, in _build_master
    return cls._build_from_requirements(__requires__)
  File "C:\Users\Dean\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 599, in _build_from_requirements
    dists = ws.resolve(reqs, Environment())
  File "C:\Users\Dean\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 792, in resolve
    raise VersionConflict(dist, req).with_context(dependent_req)
pkg_resources.ContextualVersionConflict: (Sphinx 2.4.0 (c:\users\dean\anaconda3\lib\site-packages), Requirement.parse('Sphinx>=3.0'), {'sphinx-autodoc-typehints'})
```

From what I understand, it usually shows this when you get an error but I can't see where it says there is an error. I noticed in the first traceback a VersionConflict was raised. Does this mean I installed the wrong ParlAi version?

Any sort of help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, these tracebacks indicate errors. The kinds of errors here are `pkg_resources.ContextualVersionConflict` which is kind of confusing because they don't have Error in their name. For these traceback blocks the last line is the error, the second to last is the way the error was raised.

`pkg_resources.ContextualVersionConflict: (urllib3 1.25.8 (c:\users\dean\anaconda3\lib\site-packages), Requirement.parse('urllib3~=1.25.9'), {'parlai'})`

Shows that you urllib3 is at 1.25.8, but it needs to be between 1.25.9 and 1.26.

`pkg_resources.ContextualVersionConflict: (Sphinx 2.4.0 (c:\users\dean\anaconda3\lib\site-packages), Requirement.parse('Sphinx>=3.0'), {'sphinx-autodoc-typehints'})`

means that your sphinx is 2.4.0 but should be greater than or equal to 3.0.